# TCP socket server using in6addr_any, the client can't connect use c, just using local ipv6

Tags: sockets, tcp, ipv6

TCP socket server address using **in6addr_any**, the client can't connect
(using code 1), but using local ipv6 **"fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031"**, the client can connect (using code 2). The client and server are on two tasks of the same PC. Another pc can ping6 ipv6 "fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031" successfully. But now, I just want to use code 1 instead of code 2  in the client.c and server.c on the same pc. What should I do?

a part code of server.c:

```
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;
    unsigned int addrPort = tcp_port; 
    char addrIp[] = "fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031";


    fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if( -1 == fd)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    memset_s(serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6), 0x0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    serv_addr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serv_addr->sin6_port = htons(7770);
    serv_addr->sin6_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, addrIp, &serv_addr->sin6_addr);
   // serv_addr->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    
    ret = bind(fd, serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    if(0 != ret )
    {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }    
    
    ret = listen(fd, 1);
    if(0 != ret )
    {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }    

    *server_fd = fd;
    return VOS_OK；
```

code 1:

```
   serv_addr->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
```

code 2:

```
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, addrIp, &serv_addr->sin6_addr);
```

Comment: The `fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031` address is in a Reserved range. `fc00::/7` is the ULA range, but the first half of the range (`fc00::/8`) is Reserved. You can assign addressing in the second half of the range (`fd00::/8`), but the next 40 bits must be randomly assigned, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you get 65,536 `/64` standard IPv6 networks.

Comment: In any case, if you are trying to connect to the server from the Internet, you need to use Global addressing assigned to you because ULA addressing cannot be used in the public Internet.

Comment: The server can only bind to an IP that is assigned to the machine it is running on, or the wildcard IP `::0` (aka `in6addr_any`). A client on the same network can connect to any IP the server is bound to. But a client on another network will have to connect to the server network's public WAN IP, and the network router will have to **port-forward** inbound connections from the public WAN IP to the server's LAN IP.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Sorry, it's my negligence. I forgot to say that the client and server are two tasks running on the same PC, similar to two threads.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Lebeau Sorry, I didn't make it clear. At present, my client and server are two tasks running on the same PC. I have re edited my question.

Comment: @guoyanzhang then why not simply use `::1` (the IPv6 looback IP)?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  In fact, I first make the client and server on the same PC, let the process go, and then I separate the client and server on different PCs. However, it is found that both the client and the server use in6addr_any on the same PC, and the client cannot connect to the server.

Comment: OK, I understand. I made a mistake. When the client and the server are on the same PC, the server can only use in6 addr_ any parameter, the client cannot use in6addr_ Any parameter.If the client also uses in6addr_any parameter, the connection will be rejected.

Comment: @guoyanzhang that is because you can't `connect()` to `::0`, you can only `bind()` to it. Make the server listen on `::0` and then make the client connect to any of the server's local IPs, including `::1` when on the same PC. Or else make the server listen on a specific local IP, and then make the client connect to that same IP.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau But now there is a new problem. Since the server and client are on the same PC, the server uses in6 addr_ any parameter. The client can successfully connect to the server by using the IPv6 address "fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031". That means there is no problem with the client and server code. Why is the connection rejected when I run the client to another PC? Ping6 test is successful on another PC.

Comment: @guoyanzhang Ron already explained that to you. I suggest you do some research on what [ULAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) are and how they work.